# Python: convert csv file to json file

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file to a json file by reading the content of the csv file and writing it to a new json file. I am encountering an error that is at the point where I try to make a column of the csv file into dictionary keys. How can I resolve this error?

My code for reference:

```
import csv 
import json

def jsonformat(infile,outfile):
    contents = {}
    csvfile = open(infile, 'r')
    reader = csvfile.read()

    for m in reader:
        key = m['Order ID']
        contents[key] = m
    
    jsonfile = open(outfile, 'w')
    json_contents = json.dumps(contents, indent = 4)
    jsonfile.write(json_contents)

    csvfile.close()
    jsonfile.close()
    return json_contents



infile = 'orders.csv'
outfile = 'orders.json'

output = jsonformat(infile,outfile)

print(output)
```

[image]

error message:
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
28 outfile = 'orders.json'
29
---> 30 output = jsonformat(infile,outfile)
31
32 print(output)

in jsonformat(infile, outfile)
12
13     for m in reader:
---> 14         key = m['Order ID']
15         contents[key] = m
16

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Answer (score 2):

You aren't reading the CSV file the correct way. Use `csv.DictReader` to read each row as a dictionary. Then, you'll be able to use `for m in reader: key = m['Order ID']`.

Change `reader = csvfile.read()` to `reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)`

As of now, `reader` is a string that contains all the contents of your file. `for m in reader` makes `m` each character in this string, and you cannot access the `"Order ID"` key on a character.

After you make the change, `reader` will be a `DictReader` object, and iterating over it will return each row as a dictionary.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `csv.DictReader`.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
for line in reader:
    key = line['Order ID']
    contents[key] = m
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!